# How to update a Dataframe values from an another Dataframe based on condition

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to update a "qty" column in a Dataframe based on another Dataframe "qty" column only for specific rows (according to specific types).

Here are my example Dataframes :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'op': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'C'], 'type': ['X', 'Y', 'Z', 'X', 'Z'], 'qty': [3, 1, 8, 0, 4]})
df_xy = pd.DataFrame({'op': ['A', 'B', 'C'], 'qty': [10, 20, 30]})
```

```
print(df)
print(df_xy)

  op type  qty
0  A    X    3
1  A    Y    1
2  A    Z    8
3  B    X    0
4  C    Z    4

  op  qty
0  A   10
1  B   20
2  C   30
```

I try to use the loc function to choose the concerned rows and to compare with the other Dataframe according to my reference column "op" but without success

```
# Select df rows where "type" is in "types" and set "qty" according to "qty" from df_xy
types = ['X', 'Y']
df.loc[df['type'].isin(types), 'qty'] = df_xy.loc[df_xy['op'] == df['op'], 'qty']
print(df)
```

I would like to have a Dataframe that is like this :

```
  op type  qty
0  A    X    10
1  A    Y    10
2  A    Z    8
3  B    X    20
4  C    Z    4
```

But I have an error specifying that I cannot compare Series Objects that are not labeled the same way

```
ValueError: Can only compare identically-labeled Series objects
```

Any help is much appreciated!
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could combine `loc` and [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) to align your 2 Series:

```
df.loc[df['type'].isin(types), 'qty'] = df[['op']].merge(df_xy, on='op')['qty']
```

output:

```
  op type  qty
0  A    X   10
1  A    Y   10
2  A    Z    8
3  B    X   20
4  C    Z    4
```

Answer (score 1):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) only for filtered rows in both sides for avoid processing not matched rows, here `Z` rows:

```
types = ['X', 'Y']
mask = df['type'].isin(types)
df.loc[mask, 'qty'] = df.loc[mask, 'op'].map(df_xy.set_index('op')['qty'])
print (df)
  op type  qty
0  A    X   10
1  A    Y   10
2  A    Z    8
3  B    X   20
4  C    Z    4
```

Comment: Thanks, which of these solutions do you think is more efficient, the merge or the map?

Comment: @McDeluxe - you can test in your real data, I guess `map` should be faster.

Comment: @McDeluxe - Best real data, because it depends of number of rows, number of unique values in `op`, number of matched rows.